# Ubuntu 20.04, can't drag nautilus folder tab to new window

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

Back in Ubuntu 18.04, my memory is that with multiple tabs open in nautilus (or whatever the graphical folder system is called) I could simply click and hold a tab and then dragging it outside of the current folder window would open that tab in its own window. This no longer works for me. Additionally, right clicking a tab doesn't give an "open in new window" option either.

I suppose I might be making up this functionality before, but I really thought it worked this way. So is there a simple way to move existing tabs to new windows in 20.04? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just works differently under 20.04

If you click on a folder in Nautilus (as opposed to the window header) you will be presented with a menu of options which includes `Open in New Tab` and options to`Copy,Send or Move To...`

[image]

The graphic below shows what happens when I clicked on `Open in New Tab`on `Desktop`

[image]

If (as Levente suggests) the user wishes to open a folder in a stand alone window it can be done by right clicking on the folder required and selecting `Open in New Window.`
[image]

Comment: OP could already open new tabs this way. What they are asking is how to grant such a tab a standalone window, without having to switch their attention away from that tab.

Comment: @Levente That is done by selecting the folder with right mouse click and `Open in New Window` as shown in the menu graphic.

Comment: @Levente I have updated my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 4):

The feature of "tear off" tabs indeed [was removed as it caused crashes](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/615). Apparently, no one currently is repairing or re-implementing the feature.

Still, you can quickly obtain a new window with the folder of the current tab with the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Returning to the first window, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> can then quickly remove the tab. Not quite as ideal as tear off tabs, but functionally, you also get there this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. That feature is gone..

I guess the only way to get it back is to make a bug report and tag it "wishlist".

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu